# root user terminal slower than non-root in Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, terminal

I have to quantify slow here.  It is noticeably slow, but not extreme.  Here is a test I did.
I pasted the below (time in nanoseconds command) on terminal as a non-root user and then as root user (I tried with both sudo into root or log into root with similiar results)

```
date +%s%N
date +%s%N
date +%s%N
date +%s%N
```

As non-root user I got the outputs as:

```
1609724385262715383
1609724385308203614
1609724385312504224
1609724385316730728
```

Difference of the last two: 4,226,504

As root user I got this:

```
1609724453072307276
1609724453414391531
1609724453672219226
1609724453865457590
```

Difference of the last two: 193,238,364

Why is the root terminal slow on Debian? I don't see this issue with Xenial Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Exactly what commands did you run?

Comment: Four lines of "date +%s%N" was "pasted" into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to make some wild guesses it would be;

a) Some sort of auditing or logging s/w for the root user. And this is processing\logging commands before execution.
b) Something in your\root's profile has a remote dependancy. For example attaching to a remote location to your path.
c) Something else! By that you profile is loading *something* that is hogging your CPU

What I would do is check your `profile` and `rc` files.

```
$ ls -a ~ | grep -i -e profile -e rc | grep bash
.bash_profile
.bashrc
```

Look into each of them and see if there is something strange. There may be more files than the ones above

I'm not in front of a linux machine at the moment so forgive my memory of the correct commands.

Check if there are any other processes or terminals running as `root`

```
$ w # should show logged in users and processes attached to ttys 
$ ps -ax | grep root # This will be more misleading but will show you everything running as root.
```

I hope this helps but at the moment it is of a needle in a haystack.

J

Comment: Did some more research on this and I found that on a brand new install of Debian Buster this issue does NOT happen.  And I did not modify anything in the profile from the default install.  I also stopped the Apache and MariaDB that was running.  The CPU is 100% idle and yet the same results.  So it is something I added to the system, but with Apache and MariaDB shutdown all application installs are just files. Not sure what other configuration I could have possibly changed.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking at the root home directory configuration files (the dot files).  Noticed that root .bash_history file was very large and moved to a backup file.  The response improved from >200 milliseconds to 20 milliseconds. It is still 10 times slower as the non-root user response is 2 mill-seconds. Perhaps there are more config files to look at that have grown over time.

Comment: You can [set a limit for that file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995856/212107) to prevent the issue from occuring again.

Comment: Yep! And the issue is that I set that number very high - why lose any history at all is my thinking, but there is a price to pay for it!